# Encode/decode certain text sequences in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, encoding, qt4

I have a `QTextEdit` where the user can insert arbitrary text. In this text, there may be some special sequences of characters which I wish to translate automatically. And from the translated version, I wish I could go back to the sequences.

Take for instance this:

```
QMessageBox::information(0, "Foo", MAGIC_TRANSLATE(myTextEdit->text()));
```

If the user wrote, inside `myTextEdit`'s text, the sequence `\n`, I would like that `MAGIC_TRANSLATE` converted the string `\n` to an actual new line character.

In the same way, if I give a text with a new line inside it, a `MAGIC_UNTRANSLATE` will convert the newline with a `\n` string.

Now, of course I can implement these two functions by myself, but what I am asking is if there is something already made, easy to use, in Qt, which allows me to specify a dictionary and it does the rest for me.

Note that sequences with common prefix can create some conflicts, for example converting:

```
\foo -> FOO
\foobar -> FOOBAR
```

can give rise to issues when translating the text `asd \foobar lol`, because if `\foo` is searched and replaced before `\foobar`, then the resulting text will be `asd FOObar lol` instead of the (more natural) `asd FOOBAR lol`.

I hope to have made clear my needs. I *believe* that this may be a common task, so I hope there is a Qt solution which takes into account this kind of issues when having conflicting prefixes.

I am sorry if this is a trivial topic (as I think it may be), but I am not familiar at all with encoding techniques and issues, and my knowledge of Qt encoding cover only very simple Unicode-related issues.

EDIT:
Btw, in my case a data-oriented approach, based on resources or external files or anything that does not requires a recompilation would be great.

Comment: I don't know about translating the characters in QT. But you can try the google's protobuf library. It can help you convert the special stings into binary formats and revert back also. But not sure if its gonna work for you. Probably you can pick up the logic for lookups from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is always a bit ugly to self-answer questions, but... Maybe this solution is useful to someone.

As suggested by Nicholas in his answer, a good strategy is to use replacement. It is simple and effective in most cases, for example in the plain C/C++ escaping:

```
\n \r \t etc
```

This works because they are all different. It will always work with a replacement if the sequences are all different and, in particular, if no sequence is a prefix to another sequence.

For example, if your sequences are the one aboves plus some greek letters, you will not like the `\nu` sequence, which should be translated to `ν`.

Instead, if the replacing function tests for `\n` before `\nu`, the result is wrong.

Assuming that both sequences will be translated in two completely different entities, there are two solutions: place a close-sequence character, for example `\nu;`, or just replace by longest to shorter strings. This ensure that any sequence which is prefix of another one is not replaced before it.

For various reasons, I tried another way: using a trie, which is a tree of all the prefixes of a dictionary of words. Long story short: it works fairly well and probably works faster than (most) regexes and replacements.

Regex are state machines and it is not rare to re-process the input, with a trie, you avoid to re-match characters twice, so you go pretty fast.

Code for tries is pretty easy to find on the internet, and the modifications to do efficient matching are trivial, so I will not write the code here.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your question is, "I want to run a sequence of regular expression or simple string replacements to map between two encodings of some text".

First you need to work out your mapping, exactly. As you say, if your escape sequences like \foo and \foobar are fiddly, you might find that you don't have a bidirectional, lossless mapping. No library in the world can help you if your design or encoding is flawed.

When you end up with a precise design (which we can't help you on given the complete lack of information provided on the purpose of this function), you'll probably find that a sequence of string replacements is fine. If it really is more complicated, then some QRegExps should be enough.

Comment: Thanks, but my question was more like "does Qt have something pre-made for this?". Anyway, I solved the problem using a trie. I will post an answer shortly with the details.

Comment: Well, if you have bizarre encoding scheme that may or may not even be bijective, what were you expecting..?

Comment: I expected to avoid reinventing the wheel :)